# Default custom route on SonataORMAdmin list view

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Refering to the [SoanataORMAdmin's documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-route), it is possible to change the default route of object links.

By default, it's the edit route. I don't want it at all and need to change it to show without override all my admin class.

What is the better way to override the default route ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to override the twig by extending SonataORMAdminBundle.

To do this, you need to :

- install SonataEasyGenerate Bundle
- use the command `php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataORMAdminBundle`
- this will generate a new repository Application/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle
- Then you need to go to Application/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Ressources/views/CRUD and paste the twigs from the vendors (vendor/Sonata/DoctrineORMAdminBundle/Ressources/views/CRUD)

Finally, change the links in the twigs.
For example, if you want to call the list view to call the show route for a many to one relation :

- edit list_orm_many_to_one.html.twig to call **generateObjectUrl('show',...)** instead of **generateObjectUrl('edit',...)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but already did it. I think overriding template is painful for just change a link... ;)